# failed to read the excel to sql database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, excel

I want to upload an Excel file and write data to sql server 2008.

The Excel file has 7 sheets and it writes in 7 tables.
Example : (sheetn -> temp_sheetn)

The code is working well but the last sheet is not writing in the last table.

The code is like this:

```
Partial Class app_UploadData
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim apps As New MyApps
    Dim GlobReg As Integer = 0
    Dim GlobOTC As Integer = 0

    Private dt As DataTable = Nothing

    Public Function xlsInsert(ByVal pth As String) As System.Data.DataTable
        Dim strcon As String = String.Empty
        If Path.GetExtension(pth).ToLower().Equals(".xls") OrElse Path.GetExtension(pth).ToLower().Equals(".xlsx") Then
            strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & pth & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""
        Else
            strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & pth & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
        End If
        Dim strselect As String = "Select * from [Sheet1$]"
        Dim exDT As New DataTable()
        Using excelCon As New OleDbConnection(strcon)
            Try
                excelCon.Open()
                Using exDA As New OleDbDataAdapter(strselect, excelCon)
                    exDA.Fill(exDT)
                End Using
            Catch oledb As OleDbException
                Throw New Exception(oledb.Message.ToString())
            Finally
                excelCon.Close()
            End Try
            For i As Integer = 0 To exDT.Rows.Count - 1
                ' Check if first column is empty
                ' If empty then delete such record
                If exDT.Rows(i)("CardNo").ToString() = String.Empty Then
                    exDT.Rows(i).Delete()
                End If
            Next
            exDT.AcceptChanges()
            ' refresh rows changes
            If exDT.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                Throw New Exception("File uploaded has no record found.")
            End If
            Return exDT
        End Using
    End Function

    Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim XlsConnString As String = String.Empty


        Dim DirPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Temp_Upload/")
        Dim fName As String

        If (Directory.Exists(DirPath)) Then
            For Each fName In Directory.GetFiles(DirPath)
                If File.Exists(fName) Then                    
                    File.Delete(fName)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If xlsUpload.HasFile Then
            Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(xlsUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
            Dim fileExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(xlsUpload.PostedFile.FileName)
            Dim fileLocation As String = Server.MapPath("~/Temp_Upload/" & fileName)
            xlsUpload.SaveAs(fileLocation)

            'Check whether file extension is xls or xslx
            If fileExtension = ".xls" Then
                XlsConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & fileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
            ElseIf fileExtension = ".xlsx" Then
                XlsConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileLocation & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2"""
            ElseIf fileExtension <> ".xls" Or fileExtension <> ".xlsx" Then
                lblMessage.Text = "Upload file must be excel !"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand : Dim SheetName As String 'Dim dr As SqlDataReader
            'Dim tran As SqlTransaction

            apps.OpenConnection()
            cmd.Connection = apps.oConn

            Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(XlsConnString)
            Try
                cn.Open()
            Catch ex As OleDbException
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try

            ' It Represents Excel data table Schema.
            Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
            dt = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)
            If dt IsNot Nothing OrElse dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For sheet_count As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    Try
                        ' Create Query to get Data from sheet.
                        SheetName = dt.Rows(sheet_count)("table_name").ToString()
                        'Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & sheetname & "]", cn)
                        'da.Fill(ds, sheetname)

                        'Execute a query to erase any previous data from our destination table                        
                        cmd.CommandText = "Truncate Table Temp_" & SheetName
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                        'Series of commands to bulk copy data from the excel file into our SQL table
                        Dim OleDbConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(XlsConnString)
                        Dim OleDbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(("SELECT * FROM [" & SheetName & "]"), OleDbConn)
                        'Dim OleDbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(("SELECT * FROM [Customer$]"), OleDbConn)
                        OleDbConn.Open()
                        Dim OleDbRead As OleDbDataReader = OleDbCmd.ExecuteReader()

                        Dim bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(apps.oConn)
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Temp_" & SheetName
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(OleDbRead)

                        OleDbConn.Close()
                        OleDbConn = Nothing

                    Catch ex As DataException
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                Next
            End If

            cn.Close()
            cn = Nothing

            apps.CloseConnection()

        End If


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Are you seeing an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: no error. because sheet 1 until 6. manage to write to the sql temp table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that reads

```
For sheet_count As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
```

should either be

```
For sheet_count As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
```

or

```
For sheet_count As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
```

The first one I suspect, but I can't remember if this is a zero based list as I haven't got VB.Net installed here.

Incidentally there's no need to check the file extension is .xls and then to use the Jet provider, Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 will work just fine on .xls files.

Comment: Thank you i looking all night for this